# remapping keyboard with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a jquery script for remapping the keyboard keys.
For exemple, if I press the upper arrow key, the keyboard must send the 'a' key.
I use AutoHotKey to do things like this, but I want to see if I can do the same thing with jquery.

```
var myEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown");

myEvent.which = 65;   //keycode for 'a'

$(document).keydown(function(e){

       if ( e.which === 38 ) {
               $(e.target).trigger(myEvent);
               e.preventDefault();
       }

});
```

Unfortunately don't work :(

any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown");

myEvent.which = 65;   //keycode for 'a'

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if ( e.which === 38 ) {
           $(e.target).trigger(myEvent);
           e.preventDefault();
    }
    if ( e.which === 65 ) {
        // You can call your custom function here
        console.log('a press');
    }

});
```